# How to change the templates for angular-ui properly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

Subject.

I'm going to use tabs module from this package (ui.bootstrap.tabs). I went through ui-bootstrap-tpls.js file and I saw the way the templates are defined now as

```
angular.module("template/tabs/tab.html", []).run(["$templateCache",             
function($templateCache) {

$templateCache.put("template/tabs/tab.html",
   "<li ng-class=\"{active: active, disabled: disabled}\">\n" +
   "  <a href ng-click=\"select()\" tab-heading-transclude>{{heading}}   
   /a>\n" +
   "</li>\n" +
   "");
}]);
```

So I imagined and it seemed logical to me that nested module dependency will help me to separate the templates. Something like

```
angular.module("customtab.html", []).run(["$templateCache",             
    function($templateCache) {
        //Put custom tab code into tab.html 
        $templateCache.put("template/tabs/tab.html", "..");
    }]);

angular.module("customdirective",   ["customtab.html"]).directive("customDirective")
....
```

But once I checked this with angular 1.3.5 it appeared that $templateCache is created per application. So no matter what the module dependency tree is, the $templateCache will hold content of latest put call. And thus only one version of "template/tabs/tab.html" is possible per angular application.

Is there any other way to overcome this?

**Edit 1:**
As suggested here [Can you override specific templates in AngularUI Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660947/can-you-override-specific-templates-in-angularui-bootstrap/26339919#26339919) it is possible to use $provide service. But it suffers from the same issue.
Let's say we have

```
angular.module("app.customDirective", ['ui.bootstrap.tabs',     'template/tabs/tab1.html', "template/tabs/tabset1.html"])
    .config(['$provide', function($provide){
        $provide.decorator('tabsetDirective', function($delegate) {
            var directive = $delegate[0];

            directive.templateUrl = "template/tabs/tabset1.html";

            return $delegate;
        });
        $provide.decorator('tabDirective', function($delegate) {
            var directive = $delegate[0];

            directive.templateUrl = "template/tabs/tab1.html";

            return $delegate;
        });
}])
```

This code overrides templateUrl for directives "tab" and "tabset". But even though it is run in config part of "app.customDirective" module, it *will* have impact on every other module of angular application. So once this code was run, the "tab" directive will permanently have templateUrl set to "template/tabs/tab1.html" no matter from what template of what directive it is instanced. And of course the same applies to "tabset" directive too.

Comment: Consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17660947/can-you-override-specific-templates-in-angularui-bootstrap/26339919#26339919

Comment: @JcT, unfortunatly and as I feared that solution suffers from a similar issue. The $provide is not bind to module. The changes it makes are made for whole application. I will edit the question to clarify this

Comment: Apologies, perhaps I'm still a little unclear - are you able to make use of setting the templateUrl to a function rather than a string? For example:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23999356/446030

Comment: @JcT After some additional investigation I realized that what I was trying to pull off is impossible with current module system in angular. Because as it turns out angular modules do not have a such thing as private members. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16954554/3504582 So any change made inside a module will be visible to every other module in angular application. So as I understand now, the only way to mess with templates in angularUI is what you pointed me to.