# Angular: How to create internal utils but do not export with module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, export

I am creating a angular module `MyModule`. The module contains a number of sub-modules.

```
angular.module('MyModule', [
  'MyModule.SubModule1',
  'MyModule.SubModule2',
  'MyModule.SubModule3'
]);

angular.module('MyModule.SubModule1', [
  'MyModule.Util'
]);
```

As you can see, there is the module `MyModule.Util` provides helper functions, which is actually written in a factory. No matter I explicit export `MyModule.Util` or not, it will be exported along with all my modules.

But I want this `MyModule.Util` only be used by sub-modules internally. Is that possible?

Comment: I think you can not do untill we think some hack.. here some what related thing  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16954554/2435473

Comment: @PankajParkar My case can be sightly different/easier. I want to keep some helper functions in a private namespace, not controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible in Angular as of today (v1.4.5)

Once you declare the module dependency, Angular imports all the modules from the dependency tree and makes them available to the app at large.

If you just need helper functions (as opposed to Angular services/directives/controllers), then you could just use a "private" function:

```
(function(angular){

  function privateHelperFunction1(){
  }

  angular.module("MyModule.SubModule1", [])
    .service("FooSvc", function(){
      this.doSomething = privateHelperFunction1;
    })

})(angular)
```

Comment: I appreciate your response. Looks like a doable way.

Comment: I was waiting for some other answers. As there is no, I accept yours as the best answer. Thanks.